# Recuperar variaveis data jQuery

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte botão:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#abrir-imagem" data-pasta="interno_fotos" data-imagem="139379939.jpg">Abrir Imagem</button>
```

Eu preciso recuperar ele através do Ajax. 
E fiz da seguinte forma:

```
    $('#abrir-imagem').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
        var pasta = $(this).data("pasta") 
        var imagem = $(this).data('imagem');
        $("#imagem").html("<img src='"+BASE_URL+"assets/uploads/"+pasta+"/"+imagem+"'>");
    });
```

Ele abre a modal corretamente, porém, a imagem não aparece. Diz que está indefinido as duas variáveis.
Qual é a forma correta de buscar elas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não está funcionando porque sua chamada 'não tem sentido', você está informando `$(this)` para pegar um `attr` de outro elemento.

Nesse trecho:

```
$('#abrir-imagem').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
```

Você está dizendo "quando a modal de id abrir-imagem começar a aparecer disparar", ou seja, você não vai achar os `data-attrs` de `buton` com `$(this)` quando `button` não é `$(this)`.

De forma simples, basta adicionar um `classname` identificador ao `button`, e buscar os `data-attr` através dele, como no exemplo a seguir:

```js
$('#abrir-imagem').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
        var pasta = $('.open-modal-btn').data("pasta") 
        var imagem = $('.open-modal-btn').data('imagem');
        //$("#imagem").html("<img src='"+BASE_URL+"assets/uploads/"+pasta+"/"+imagem+"'>");
        console.log('Pasta:' + pasta + '| Imagem: ' +imagem )
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="button" class="open-modal-btn btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#abrir-imagem" data-pasta="interno_fotos" data-imagem="139379939.jpg">Abrir Imagem</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="abrir-imagem" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Troque o código JavaScript por este:

```
$('#abrir-imagem').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
  var pasta = $(this).attr('data-pasta');
  var imagem = $(this)attr('data-imagem');

  $("#imagem").html("<img src='"+BASE_URL+"assets/uploads/"+pasta+"/"+imagem+"'>");
});
```